# py3k print significant figures

Tags: printing, python-3.x, significant-digits

In python3 is there a nice way to set significant figures - i.e if I have a list:

```
l = [2.2738257169723513, 2.2725769281387329, 2.3101812601089478]
```

I can use the nice new print system and do

```
print(*l,sep="\t")
```

But I'm unclear as to how to set the sigfig with out doing

```
m = "%.2f, %.2f, %.2f" % (l[0], l[1], l[2])
print(m)
```

I was wondering if there was an option to print to just say - print all floats to 2 dp?

I guess I could use a loop but that seems not very Python like

Comment: I'd suggest you to clarify if you mean significant figures or significant decimal places.

Comment: Then I think the title and content of the question should be re-factored, otherwise the question is unrelated to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is definitely pythonic, and it is the only way to do what you're asking. That said, you can still use a comprehension to make this more concise (in this cause a tuple, but you can use a list or use `list(map(`):

```python
# I've changed the name to float_list because l should not be
# used as a variable name in Python according to the standard
# style recommendations
print(*('{0:.2f}'.format(x) for x in float_list), sep="\t")
```

Comment: Yuck, definitely not good Python 3 style. `str.format` should be used. And... camelCase? Really?

Comment: @BlaXpirit Sorry, old habits die hard. (`<smarmy>`That was mixedCase, not CamelCase, BTW `</smarmy>`)